# Not as what I thought it would be OR not as I thought it would be

Tags: phrases

Let's say Youtube videos always have a "clickbait" modus, that is, they have **catchy title**, BUT when click them, they are fake.  it goes like this:

> Youtube videos always have a catchy title, but when you click them, **not as WHAT I thought it would be** (fake)

Or

> Youtube videos always have a catchy title, but when you click them, **not as I thought it would be** (fake)

Which is correct here really? They both kinda ok to me with not much of a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposed alternative:

> Youtube videos always have a catchy title, but when you click them, they are often not what you expected them to be.

- "videos" is plural. "it" is singular. This is a mismatch. Change "it" to "they" or "them".
- If "you" click, then it's about what "you" thought. Stay consistent. Don't switch back and forth from "you" to "I".
- A sentence needs a subject and a verb.  Sometimes, even a clause within a sentence needs a subject and a verb, as seems to be the case here, so add "they are".
- (fake) is just appended there... Omit it. Or, put a sentence instead: "In fact, they are totally fake."

Next, should it be "what" or "as".

> 1. not what you expected

or

> 2. not as you expected

or

> 3. not what you thought

or

> 4. not as you thought

Any of those will work.

However, "what" seems a bit more solid of a choice than "as". Especially in case #4, in my personal opinion, where it seems a bit less than optimal.

Comment: Oh man, I can't thank you enough. Are **expected** and **thought** the same here in this context? I've noticed you also changed that.

Comment: @JohnArvin In this context, they are similar words. You may consider using "expect" instead.  "thought" is still alright.